# rubber stuck compiling ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

for some reason whenever i try to spawn a server with rubber it gets stuck after compiling ruby-1.9.2.

If I SSH into the server, I see that before it finishes compiling, almost at the very end, the rubber script disconnects the connection.

```
** [out :: stageone.foo.com] ruby-1.9.2-p0 - #compiling
```

If I try to do cap rubber:bootstrap it fails at trying to install mongrel citing that my ruby installation might not be complete.

Fetching: mongrel-1.1.5.gem (100%)39%)
 ** Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
 ** ERROR:  Error installing mongrel:
 ** ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 ** 
 ** /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb

I'm trying to create a staging server using the "complete_mongrel_mysql" script.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation is on the mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubber-ec2/K-ahRFZpAAk/2fTJI5EeURwJ

Workaround checked into code for next release at:

https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber/commit/64299e2005dcae9006273a6f915bf01dd8c87192

Comment: Thanks Kevin! :) I posted here before i found the goog groups